# jQuery click event not working for p tag class

Tags: jquery, html

I am generating an output of options selected from drop down list.
I want to allow the user to 'remove' selections from the output.

I can't get my code to work though, here is the code which renders the output:

```
 $('#dataCombo').change(function(){
 $('#dataOutput').html('');
 var values = $('#dataCombo').val();
 for(var i = 0; i < values.length; i += 1) {
 $('#dataOutput').append(values[i] + '<p class="removeable">X</p>'+'<br/>')
 }});
```

So the selected drop down item is displayed on the page with a 'X' next to it in P tags with the class "removable", generated.  I've inspected this in chrome and the p tag is created with the correct class.

I added this code to remove the clicked option however it doesnt work:

```
$('.removeable').click(function(){
$('.removeable').remove();
console.log("I did this"); 
});
```

The item doesn't get removed, i don't get a log in the console.  Any idea why this wouldnt work?

EDIT:

I've amended my code to this:

```
$('#dataOutput').append('<p class="removeable">' + values[i] + 'X</p>'+'<br/>')
```

And it does indeed remove the item, however the option is still 'selected' in the drop down box.  I was trying to get it to 'unselect' this as well.  I'm using Bootstrap and a drop down with 'multiple' activated.  While the option is currently removed from the output, it's not removed from the select box (meaning when another option is clicked it re-renders the previously removed element).

I've asked the question (hopefully) more clearly, in a different way to the duplicated question:
[Unselect an option using jQuery on a Bootstrap selectpicker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22606542/unselect-an-option-using-jquery-on-a-bootstrap-selectpicker)

Comment: Nobody has explained that when the browser is executing your `$('.removeable').click(function(){});` line the `p` elements do not exist yet, so the click handler will not be bound. You need to tell jQuery to bind the click handler on an ancestor element (that **does** exist on the page at that time) and get the click event delegated down to your `p`.

Comment: Finally, you'll probably want to remove the `p`'s parent (or further up ancestor - depending on your markup) otherwise all that code will do is remove the `X`

Comment: yes thats right, currently what the code is doing is just removing the X, and not the option itself

Comment: Without seeing more of the HTML, it is difficult to answer with the correct jQuery to remove the _selection_. This question is now marked as duplicate because event delegation in jQuery has been covered before. Check out the link at the top of this question for information about event delegation. If you are having a problem after that, please ask another question about removing the correct element and supply the relevant HTML and JavaScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) and please use `$(this)` reference inside of that click handler, If you dont use that, then while clicking on a single element results in removing all those elements with that class

```
$("#dataOutput").on('click','.removeable',function(){
 $(this).remove();
 console.log("I did this"); 
});
```

And also note that, always prefer the closest static parent for delegating the events

Comment: I didn't downvote you, but all the answers are being downvoted (I saw Felix go from 3 to -1 and now back to 1...) Weird...

Comment: Thanks for this, it is now indeed removing the element however it is only removing the 'X' and not the selected option inside the tag.
So it's removing the `<p class="removeable">X</p>` but not the item inside.  (Also i didn't vote you down just incase you thought it was me)

Comment: Please show the rendered html of yours, so that we could write code that would suit your requirement.. :)

Comment: I changed the order of the html elements so the while thing was removed, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Since your paragraphs have been added dynamically to the DOM, the click event will not be available for these paragraph. In this case, **[event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)** will help you to attach that event to these dynamically generated paragraphs:

> Event delegation allows us to attach a single event listener, to a
>   parent element, that will fire for all children matching a selector,
>   whether those children exist now or are added in the future.

```
$('#dataOutput').on('click', '.removeable', function() {
    $(this).remove();
    console.log("I did this"); 
});
```

Also, instead of removing all the `.removeable` on click of any paragraph with class `removeable`, you can target only the clicked paragraph using `$(this)` inside your click handler.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, however this technique only seems to remove `<p class="removeable">X</p>` and not the item within.  Any idea how i can  fix that?

Comment: What elements that you want to remove when click on the paragraph? Can you be more specific?